# Do I lose my jQuery bindings if I refresh part of the DOM?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("input[id^='Position_'], select[id^='Level_'], input[id^='Title_'], select[id^='Status_'],").change(function (e) {
              var type = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[0];
              updateField('Menu', $(this), type);
          });
      });
   </script>
```

This works fine. However I use Ajax to refresh an area of the page with new HTMl, same field and id names but just data sorted in a different order.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Administration/" + entity + "s/Detail2",
    data: { pk: pk },
    dataType: 'html',
    cache: false,
    success: function (responseText) {
        $('#detailData').html(responseText);
    }
});
```

After this refresh the function updateField doesn't get called.

Is this expected behaviour or am I making some mistakes in another area.

Also. I am using IE for my debug. Is there a way I can see bindings such as these where the updateField is bound to elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your example, as you are changing the `html()` of the container, then all the events attached to those elements will be removed too.

To prevent this, use `delegate()` (or `on()` if you are using 1.7+) on the container to check the elements inside it. Don't use `live()` as it has been deprecated and has poor performance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#detailData").delegate("input[id^='Position_'], select[id^='Level_'], input[id^='Title_'], select[id^='Status_'],", "change", function (e) {
            var type = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[0];
            updateField('Menu', $(this), type);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I am using 1.7+ so if I use on() do I just replace the word delegate with "on" in the above?

Comment: @Melissa to use on, it would be `$("#detailData").on("change", "input[id^='Position_'], ...", function (e) {`

Answer (score 0):

I think though `id`s are same still they are newly added HTML elements with no events bind to them. So it is expected behavior.
To bind Jquery event to newly added element use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
**PS:** `.live()` is deprecated in Jquery 1.7.

**EDIT:**
Use `.live()` while binding events in Jquery like

```
$("p").live("click", function(){
  $(this).after("<p>Another paragraph!</p>");
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. How should I use this. I already bound to elements with the same ID names. Is that all lost when I replace those elements with elements of the same name?

Answer (score 0):

By default you'll lose the bindings, but there are techniques which enable you to have bindings which associate with new content as it's created...
http://api.jquery.com/live/